# Including log file name in log entry in Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I have a requirement to include the name of the log file in the log entry itself.

For example say final name of the log file is something like `trx_log.2014-09-22-12-42` the log entries I'm printing that log should have that same name. Following is a example log entry.

```
123456|test value|xyz|trx_log.2014-09-22-12-42
```

I'm using Log4j `DailyRollingFileAppender` to print the log at the moment. Is there a way which I can get this requirement implemented using some log4j/logback configuration.

Comment: I appologize. but why?!!?!?!??! this is just a waste of space....

Comment: why not try the simple approach of appending trx_log.2014-09-22-12-42 to your log statements from you classes. This is good in case if you are implementing logger from scratch in your prj but in other case can you check the pattern layout for your appender where you can configure the ConversionPattern

Comment: Yes I know that appending file name is a waste of time. But that is the requirement of the CDR log I have to print :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

But a solution does exist nevertheless: write your own custom extension of the `DailyRollingFileAppender`.

Please note though the filename will be available to your custom appender only: in case you want to use such information in another appender (the only use case I can think of this might be of any use) then you need a more convoluted solution using a shared data storage (shared memory, file system, database, whatever) with the simplest solution being a static member of your just made appender. In this case the other appender (lat's say Console) need to be extended as well in order to append the new information to the log statement.

Comment: I was also thinking about extending `RollingFileAppender` and implement custom one. Just wanted to check whether there is a another way of doing it, through some configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Use this method logger.getName()

logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception in "+e.getMessage()+logger.getName());

Comment: That prints the class FQN or anything else used to name the current logger, not the filename where the log entry is going to be written as that information is obscured to the logger and available only within the appender.